# Debug PHP using Docker in VSCode

Tags: php, docker, debugging, xdebug, vscode-debugger

It looks like everything is OK, but VSCode does not stop debugging. I have a docker container running a PHP image.

What I need to do to stop in the break points?

I can't see errors in the log, quite the contrary, it seems that they are saying that the break points were well configured, and that the code ran correctly.

- The container has the IP **172.22.0.2**, my host has the IP **172.22.0.1**
- The file **xdebugo.so** exists inside the container: 
  `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so`
- The host **host.docker.internal** was set up correctly.
- I built my image using: `docker build -t phpdebug:5 .`
- The file `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini` exists in the running container.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    restart: 'no'
    image: phpdebug:5
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - phpdata:/app
    environment:
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1

volumes:
  phpdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/home/element/php/tuto'
```

**/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/xdebug.log
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.22.0.2  d484e93eed2a
172.22.0.1      host.docker.internal
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php

RUN pecl install xdebug

RUN ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 "host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts

COPY custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

**/usr/local/etc/php/xdebug.log**

```
[1] Log opened at 2020-02-25 03:31:45
[1] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
[1] I: Connected to client. :-)
[1] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="1" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 1
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 2
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="2"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 3 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php -n 2
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3" id="10001"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php -n 10
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="10002"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php -n 4
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="10003"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 6
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="6"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10001"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10002"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10003"></breakpoint></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 7
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="7"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10001"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10002"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10003"></breakpoint></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x *
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="10004"></response>

[1] <- run -i 9
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="9" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[1] <- stop -i 10
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="10" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[1] Log closed at 2020-02-25 03:31:45

[1] Log opened at 2020-02-25 03:31:48
[1] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
[1] I: Connected to client. :-)
[1] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/dies.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="1" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 1
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 2
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="2"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 3 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php -n 2
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3" id="10005"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php -n 10
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="10006"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php -n 4
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="10007"></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 6
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="6"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10005"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10006"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10007"></breakpoint></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_list -i 7
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="7"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="2" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10005"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/dies.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10006"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="10007"></breakpoint></response>

[1] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x *
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="10008"></response>

[1] <- run -i 9
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="9" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[1] <- stop -i 10
[1] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="10" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[1] Log closed at 2020-02-25 03:31:48
```

**debug console in vscode:**

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}
new connection 1
<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'started', threadId: 1 }
}
<- initializedEvent
InitializedEvent { seq: 0, type: 'event', event: 'initialized' }
-> setBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  arguments: {
    source: { name: 'dies.php', path: '/home/element/php/tuto/dies.php' },
    lines: [ 2, 10 ],
    breakpoints: [ { line: 2 }, { line: 10 } ],
    sourceModified: false
  },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 3
}
-> setBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  arguments: {
    source: { name: 'result.php', path: '/home/element/php/tuto/result.php' },
    lines: [ 4 ],
    breakpoints: [ { line: 4 } ],
    sourceModified: false
  },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 4
}
<- setBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 3,
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: {
    breakpoints: [ { verified: true, line: 2 }, { verified: true, line: 10 } ]
  }
}
<- setBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 4,
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [ { verified: true, line: 4 } ] }
}
-> setFunctionBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { breakpoints: [] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 5
}
<- setFunctionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 5,
  command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [] }
}
-> setExceptionBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { filters: [ '*' ] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 6
}
<- setExceptionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 6,
  command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  success: true
}
-> configurationDoneRequest
{ command: 'configurationDone', type: 'request', seq: 7 }
<- configurationDoneResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 7,
  command: 'configurationDone',
  success: true
}
<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'exited', threadId: 1 }
}
-> threadsRequest
{ command: 'threads', type: 'request', seq: 8 }
<- threadsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 8,
  command: 'threads',
  success: true,
  body: { threads: [] }
}
-> threadsRequest
{ command: 'threads', type: 'request', seq: 9 }
<- threadsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 9,
  command: 'threads',
  success: true,
  body: { threads: [] }
}
new connection 2
<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'started', threadId: 2 }
}
<- initializedEvent
InitializedEvent { seq: 0, type: 'event', event: 'initialized' }
-> setBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  arguments: {
    source: { name: 'dies.php', path: '/home/element/php/tuto/dies.php' },
    lines: [ 2, 10 ],
    breakpoints: [ { line: 2 }, { line: 10 } ],
    sourceModified: false
  },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 10
}
-> setBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  arguments: {
    source: { name: 'result.php', path: '/home/element/php/tuto/result.php' },
    lines: [ 4 ],
    breakpoints: [ { line: 4 } ],
    sourceModified: false
  },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 11
}
<- setBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 10,
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: {
    breakpoints: [ { verified: true, line: 2 }, { verified: true, line: 10 } ]
  }
}
<- setBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 11,
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [ { verified: true, line: 4 } ] }
}
-> setFunctionBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { breakpoints: [] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 12
}
<- setFunctionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 12,
  command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [] }
}
-> setExceptionBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { filters: [ '*' ] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 13
}
<- setExceptionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 13,
  command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  success: true
}
-> configurationDoneRequest
{ command: 'configurationDone', type: 'request', seq: 14 }
<- configurationDoneResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 14,
  command: 'configurationDone',
  success: true
}
<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'exited', threadId: 2 }
}
-> threadsRequest
{ command: 'threads', type: 'request', seq: 15 }
<- threadsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 15,
  command: 'threads',
  success: true,
  body: { threads: [] }
}
-> threadsRequest
{ command: 'threads', type: 'request', seq: 16 }
<- threadsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 16,
  command: 'threads',
  success: true,
  body: { threads: [] }
}
```

I tried the answers here:
[Debugging Laravel with VSCode on Docker container using Xdebug as debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175004/debugging-laravel-with-vscode-on-docker-container-using-xdebug-as-debugger/53576174#53576174)

and here:
[Debug PHP with VSCode and Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579102/debug-php-with-vscode-and-docker?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log shows in the `<init` packet:

```
file:///app/index.php
```

And all the breakpoints are configured like:

```
file:///home/element/php/tuto/result.php
```

This indicates that the path mappings that you have made, are not correct:

```
"pathMappings": {
    "/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
}
```

In your case, I believe it should be the following, providing that both these directories have an `index.php` and `result.php` file. If not, you need to adjust the second path so that is the path that has the `index.php` and `result.php` files.

```
"pathMappings": {
    "/app": "/home/element/php/tuto"
}
```